# VS Code Go to Implementations / Definition (aka F12, aka CTRL+click) doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-code

Normally when I choose either "Go to Definition" or "Go to Implementations" from the context menu on a function name of a function definition in a JavaScript file, or press `F12` or `CTRL+Click` on the function name, VS Code shows in a popup all the places across the project where that function is used.

For some reason this doesn't work with some of my projects.

Here is a simple repro structure that still has the problem for me:

```
foo.js
bar
  |_ bar.js
```

```js
// foo.js
import bar from './bar/bar';


export const foo = () => {
    bar();
};
```

```js
// bar/bar.js

export default function bar() {
    console.log('function bar called')
}
```

That's all.

The command works fine when both files are open in the editor. The command also works if both files are in the same directory, no matter root or deeper. If I rename or move one of the files, the changes get correctly automatically reflected in the import line of the other file, which means VS Code understands the file structure.

Why doesn't the definitions / implementations popup appear, neither for `.js` files, nor for `.ts` files?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with your repro. Is your repro missing any files? tsconfig.json? jsconfig.json?

Comment: @user, no, it's not. Only those two files. I also tried deleting my user `settings.json`, but it didn't help. I tried deactivating all extensions too with no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **must** include a `jsconfig.json` or a `tsconfig.json` file in the root of your project in order for the InteliSense to understand that you are indeed inside a JavaScript project and to link the files together rather than treating them as separate entities. See [details on jsconfig.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig) in VS Code documentation.